# Vert.x - what's missing for Scala?

Tags: scala, clojure, vert.x

The Vert.x [documentation](http://vertx.io/manual.html#verticle) says that Scala (and Clojure) will be supported 'soon'.
What's actually missing for using it with Scala as is??

Comment: There's a scala language mod https://github.com/vert-x/mod-lang-scala Best to ask this question on the vert.x message board https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/vertx as that is where all the developers reside.

Comment: Thanks, will post the answer here.

Answer (score 5):

So, [as of 2013/11/04](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vertx/o8PwJBPeptI/w7LvevUDQ8gJ):

> Scala support has everything up to Vert.x 2.0.2-final plus DNS support. So you need 2.1M1 of Vert.x core and the 0.2.0 release of Scala.
>   We need to add UDP support, EventBus timeouts (mostly done, but there seems to be a bug in the vert.x core project: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=420850 ), provide asynchronous registerHandler methods (as these changed to async style) and provide a solution for the unregisterHandler problem we were facing (probably use the asynchronous registerHandler to provide a RegisteredHandler object that has an unregisterHandler() method).

and [a followup](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vertx/o8PwJBPeptI/3K7ovwCWUikJ)

> Update: EventBus timeouts are done, waiting for review in pull request https://github.com/vert-x/mod-lang-scala/pull/77
>   I forgot to mention that HTTP Compression was also missing. Just added another PR to review here: https://github.com/vert-x/mod-lang-scala/pull/78
>   Also added docs for both of them.
>
> To recap what's still missing:
>
> - UDP support + test + docs
> - asynchronous registerHandler methods + test + docs
> - unregisterHandler issue + tests + docs (I guess this should be done with the asynchronous registerHandler providing a AsyncResult[RegisteredHandler] => Unit callback)

Also [announced today](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/ekvCi8VQt9U):

> I'm really proud to announce the release of Vert.x Scala 0.2.0 which includes full Vert.x 2.0 API support as well as new DNS API support coming up in Vert.x 2.1. This means that mod-lang-scala 0.2.0 now requires Vert.x 2.1.
>
> The amazing API work has been driven by the tireless Joern Bernhardt and his colleague Sascha Schmidt. Between them two they've added all the missing APIs and reworked the testsuite to add Scala specific testtools. This was a big tasks and both Joern and Sascha deserve full credit for pulling this off. Kudos to both for this fantastic work!! :). On top of this, we've also added the capability to deploy Scala scripts into Vert.x, bringing the Vert.x Scala examples in line with other languages.
>
> For next release, 0.3.0, we'll be focusing on polishing some these APIs, adding new APIs that Vert.x 2.1 brings, documentation and more examples :)
>
> While we complete the documentation, the best place to get started with the Scala language module is to look at the README file in the Vert.x mod-lang-scala repository.